# rmdir works only if header is not used afterwards

Tags: php

```
if (is_dir($dir)) {
  if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {
    while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
      if (is_file($dir .'/'. $file))
        unlink($dir .'/'. $file);
    }
  closedir($dh);
  }
}
rmdir($dir);
header('Location: /account/control/sell/step-one/');
exit();
```

Remove directory rmdir() won't work when I place header() immediately below. I can comment out (//) header() and rmdir will work perfectly.

I've tried deleting the files using glob and scandir. There are many answers to questions on StackOverflow about deleting files and directories. I have tried several functions I have found on StackOverflow.

Many work just find provided I do not use the header() function. It's the rmdir/header combination that causing the problem.

Comment: funny because that rm code should generate a lot of errors most of the time, the way it potentially tries to delete .. folders over and over and over. - also to make it more portable, you should use the `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` constant, not hardcode `'/'`

Comment: perhaps `foreach((new RecursiveIteratorIterator((new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir,FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS | FilesystemIterator::CURRENT_AS_FILEINFO )))) as $file){unlink($file->getRealPath());}` (untested)

Answer (score 0):

```
function delFolder($dir){
   $glob = glob($dir.'/{,.}*',GLOB_BRACE);
   if(!empty($glob)){
      foreach($glob as $val){
         if(basename($val) != '.' && basename($val) != '..'){
            if(is_dir($val)){ 
               delFolder($val);
            };
            if(is_file($val)){
               unlink($val);
            };
         };
      };
   };
   rmdir($dir);
};

delFolder($dir);
header('Location: /account/control/sell/step-one/');
exit();
```

Comment: Your function works when I comment out the header() function. When I use header() it deletes the files but won't delete the folder. There are similar functions on StackOverflow that I have tried. They do the same thing. It's a shared hosting I have got. It may be the way the hosting is configured.The hosting technical support told me to use or incorporate a ssh type force directive like -f or -rf into my code.